# Docker user permission while mounting a directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using the following Dockerfile to build Solr using Docker.

```
FROM solr:5.5
ENV SOLR_HOME=/opt/solr/server/solr/cores
RUN mkdir ${SOLR_HOME}
RUN chown -R solr:solr ${SOLR_HOME}
VOLUME ["${SOLR_HOME}"]
EXPOSE 8983
```

I try to run the following Docker command to mount a host directory to the container:

```
docker run --restart=always -d --name solr-demo \
--privileged=true -p 8983:8983 \
-v /data/solr_demo:/opt/solr/server/solr/cores \
solr-test:latest
```

I  am also copying the required `solr.xml` file into the `data/solr_demo`. When I run the `docker run` command I get the following error:

```
stat: cannot stat ‘/opt/solr/server/solr/cores’: No such file or directory 42146d74b446ba4784fd197688e3210f294aad8755ae730cc559132720bcc35a
Error response from daemon: Container 42146d74b446ba4784fd197688e3210f294aad8755ae730cc559132720bcc35a is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /data/solr_demo` on the host? Also, what is the output from `docker run --rm --privileged=true solr-test:latest ls -l /opt/solr/server/solr/cores`?

Comment: Hi please find the outputs [root@ip-10-0-2-15 data]# ls -ld /data/solr-demo1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 21 Jun  7 12:20 /data/solr-demo1  [root@ip-10-0-2-15 build]# docker run --rm --privileged=true solr-test:latest ls -l /opt/solr/server/solr/cores
total 0

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it appears you're mounting a nonexistent directory for your volume. Try this command that mounts /data/solr_demo**1** instead of /data/solr_demo as your volume.

```
docker run --restart=always -d --name solr-demo \
--privileged=true -p 8983:8983 \
-v /data/solr_demo1:/opt/solr/server/solr/cores \
solr-test:latest
```

Comment: hey BMitch thanks for your concern .a small update . if i give chmod 777 to data/solr_demo1 then it is working correctly with the solr.xml placed inside it . what should i do to eliminate the permissions.and it is able to mount the cores directory as needed .

Comment: With host based volumes, you currently need to mirror the user's uid used on the host and inside the container. If you run "id" on the host, and `docker run --rm solr-test:latest id` you should see the uid on each side. You may find it easier to modify the group membership of the user in the container to match a group you are a member of (adding a `RUN usermod -aG ...` to your Dockerfile). The other option is to switch to named volumes.

Comment: tried adding usermod -aG 1000 solr , but no luck , it says the user is already used by resource 1.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really an user problem (it remind me of some issue I add with apache in container), you should consider using Gosu. https://github.com/tianon/gosu

It will let you run and swap user correctly and have a nice mapping from your local users and users inside the container.

Hope it will be useful.